# How come Grafana and Prometheus are producing different results from each other?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

same query but different result

I think there's an issue on grafana when use count_over_time.

is there anyone who can explain this??

grafana dashboard
query : count_over_time(certificates_created{}[5d:5m])

[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmKkI.png)

[grafana dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w4n3.png)

prometheus web ui dashboard
query : count_over_time(certificates_created{}[5d:5m])

[prometheus web ui dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmNOz.png)

I expect that result is same with prometheus one.
but I'm using grafana dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bug/coincidence of some sort at Grafana's side.

Most likely reason for this is that Grafana requesting data at "round" times, when 5 days indeed contain 1441 value (both boundaries are included into time range, for some reason)

Best what you can do at this situation is to file an [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues). Here are links for your issue: demo at [play.grafana.com](https://play.grafana.org/explore?orgId=1&left=%7B%22datasource%22:%22000000008%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22prometheus%22,%22uid%22:%22000000008%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22,%22expr%22:%22count_over_time%28up%5B5d:5m%5D%29%22,%22legendFormat%22:%22__auto%22,%22range%22:true,%22instant%22:true%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-1h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D), demo at [prometheus](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=count_over_time(up%7B%7D%5B5d%3A5m%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h).